# logical help needed for selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have tricky situation in one of application which needs to be automated
scenario : User can enter data in the application maximum of 4 times in a day. 5th Time when user press enter/submit button then a warring msg is displayed.

```
" div.container-fluid::before"
<div class="alert alert-warning fade in">Maximum entries reached."</div>"
```

this is the HTML element. 
This comes only after 4 times of entry. Until 4th time this element will not appear
Situation to automate: First check that error message is displayed by press submit button. If error message is not displayed continue to for loop else quit the application. 
But script is failing because if error message is not displayed it is telling 
no such element: Unable to locate element: "Xpath"
I tried  following but seems not working :

```
wd = launchBrowser ("chrome" );
        wd.get(“website link “);


wd.findElement(By.xpath(“.//*[@id='user_email']")).sendKeys(“UI”);
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_password']")).sendKeys("pwd”);
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='new_user']/div[3]/input")).click();

wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'btn btn-primary')]")).click(); //will navigate to data adding page.

wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"new_entry\"]/input[3]")).click(); 
// this is the submit button 

Thread.sleep(1000);
String x = wd.findElement(By.xpath(" .//*[contains(@class, 'alert alert-warning fade in')]")).toString();
//This is the xpath which comes only if the data entered is already 4 times

if(x == null ) 
{
 For(condition for 4 times to enter) 
}
Else{
sysout(“Max number of times per is done”);
}
wd.quit();
}
```

Comment: Can you do that block of code in `try-catch` block ?

Comment: Your quotation marks seem incorrect, does this even compile? You sometimes use `“` and `”` for `String`s but it should be `"`. Also, what is `For(condition for 4 times to enter)`, does not look like valid Java.

Comment: Try catch for only String x or from String x until end of the Else .. ?

Comment: Yes it comes but bad luck in run time getting error @Zabuza

Comment: @Ayodhyankit Paul.  Your suggestion worked and my script is running successfully without any issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ABAJAVa if worked then you can accept my answer :)

Comment: @Ayodhyankit Paul how to accept , I am new to this site. there was ^ I have clicked it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Try and Catch` block to try if enter/submit button  is already pressed 4 times and if it give error `"catch`" that error.

This line :

```
String x = wd.findElement(By.xpath(" .//*[contains(@class, 'alert alert-warning fade in')]")).toString();
```